# Why does this XML validation via XSD fail in libxml2 (but succeed in xmllint) and how do I fix it?

Tags: c, xml, macos, xsd, libxml2

If I run this **XML validation** via **xmllint:**

```
xmllint --noout --schema schema.xsd test.xml
```

I get this **success** message:

```
.../test.xml validates
```

However if I run the **same validation** via **libxml2's C API:**

```
int result = xmlSchemaValidateDoc(...)
```

I get a **return value of `1845`** and this **failure** message:

```
Element '{http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0}foo': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

Which I can make absolutely no sense of. :(

---

**schema.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE xs:schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN" "XMLSchema.dtd" >
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0" targetNamespace="http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="foo">
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<foo xmlns="http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0">
</foo>
```

---

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/valid.h>
#include <libxml/xmlschemas.h>

u_int32_t get_file_size(const char *file_name) {
    struct stat buf;
    if ( stat(file_name, &buf) != 0 ) return(0);
    return (unsigned int)buf.st_size;
}

void handleValidationError(void *ctx, const char *format, ...) {
    char *errMsg;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vasprintf(&errMsg, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, "Validation Error: %s", errMsg);
    free(errMsg);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char *xsdPath = argv[1];
    const char *xmlPath = argv[2];

    printf("\n");

    printf("XSD File: %s\n", xsdPath);
    printf("XML File: %s\n", xmlPath);

    int xmlLength = get_file_size(xmlPath);
    char *xmlSource = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * xmlLength);

    FILE *p = fopen(xmlPath, "r");
    char c;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(p)) != EOF) {
        xmlSource[i++] = c;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("XML Source:\n\n%s\n", xmlSource);
    fclose(p);

    printf("\n");

    int result = 42;
    xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr parserCtxt = NULL;
    xmlSchemaPtr schema = NULL;
    xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr validCtxt = NULL;

    xmlDocPtr xmlDocumentPointer = xmlParseMemory(xmlSource, xmlLength);
    parserCtxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt(xsdPath);

    if (parserCtxt == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create XSD schema parsing context.\n");
        goto leave;
    }

    schema = xmlSchemaParse(parserCtxt);

    if (schema == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse XSD schema.\n");
        goto leave;
    }

    validCtxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);

    if (!validCtxt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create XSD schema validation context.\n");
        goto leave;
    }

    xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc(NULL, NULL);
    xmlSetGenericErrorFunc(NULL, handleValidationError);
    xmlThrDefSetStructuredErrorFunc(NULL, NULL);
    xmlThrDefSetGenericErrorFunc(NULL, handleValidationError);

    result = xmlSchemaValidateDoc(validCtxt, xmlDocumentPointer);

leave:

    if (parserCtxt) {
        xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt(parserCtxt);
    }

    if (schema) {
        xmlSchemaFree(schema);
    }

    if (validCtxt) {
        xmlSchemaFreeValidCtxt(validCtxt);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Validation successful: %s (result: %d)\n", (result == 0) ? "YES" : "NO", result);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**console output:**

```
XSD File: /Users/dephiniteloop/Desktop/xml_validate/schema.xsd
XML File: /Users/dephiniteloop/Desktop/xml_validate/test.gkml

XML Source:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<foo xmlns="http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0">
</foo>

Validation Error: Element '{http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0}foo': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.

Validation successful: NO (result: 1845)
```

---

In case it matters: I'm on **OSX 10.6.7** with its default **libxml2.dylib**
(/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.7.3.dylib)

Comment: Are you sure you're providing the schema to libxml2? You left out the critical part of the invocation in your code sample.

Comment: @JimGarrison Well, if I introduce a typo or wrong semantic to my xsd schema, then `xmlSchemaParse(…)` fails and I get an appropriate error message (e.g. "The attribute 'use' is not allowed"). Same goes for adding syntax errors to my xml file. Throws appropriate errors. So I suppose, yes I do. I however cannot get this particular error to go away, even though from my point of view it makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. *sigh*

Comment: @jim-garrison: I added the straight forward C code that I'm using along with the one console output it produces for me, every single time I run it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting some help on the **gnome project's xml mailing-list** it appears as if my **error is not caused by a bug of mine**, but **rather by a bug of OSX 10.6.x's distribution (v2.7.3) of libxml2**.
(as in: same code works for others, yet fails for me OSX' legacy distribution)

I checked the libxml2 release notes and found two candidates:

Release notes of Update 2.7.4 list the following bug fix:

- "579746 XSD validation not correct / nilable groups (Daniel Veillard)"

Release notes of Update 2.7.8 list the following bug fix:

- "Fix errors in XSD double validation check (Csaba Raduly)"

Haven't yet had success getting the latest build (v2.7.8) of libxml2 to work with my project (or rather Xcode in general) though.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your content and code on Ubuntu Linux. Worked without any objection.

Build command:

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 main.c -lxml2 -o xmlvalid
```

Run command:

```
./xmlvalid ./schema.xsd ./test.xml
```

Output:

```
XSD File: ./schema.xsd
XML File: ./test.xml
```

XML Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<foo xmlns="http://example.com/XMLSchema/1.0">
</foo>
```

Validation successful: YES (result: 0)

Answer (score 1):

Your schema puts the element foo into the targetNamespace (that's what elementdefault="qualified" means), but your instance document doesn't declare that namespace or any other.  So the foos don't actually match.

Comment: Would you mind posting a snippet of what I have to change and to what? The XML/XSD/XMLNS terminology is still rather new to me. Would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is very confusing because it allows questions to be changed after they have been answered: but the version of the instance document I see in front of me is indeed in a namespace.

Comment: I certainly didn't change anything in the meanwhile.

Comment: cowan, @michael-kay: I added the straight forward C code that I'm using along with the one console output it produces for me, every single time I run it.